# HTTP Response Behaviour

Tags: asp.net, http, http-headers, fiddler, httpresponse

I have two very similar pieces of ASP.NET code that send a file in an HTTP Reponse to the client. They should cause the browser to prompt to save the file. The first one works, the second one doesn't. The HTTP responses as seen in Fiddler are below.

Working:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 228108
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
content-disposition: attachment; filename=Report.xlsx
Date: Wed, 05 Jan 2011 12:17:48 GMT
<binary data>
```

Not working:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date: Wed, 05 Jan 2011 12:19:21 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Content-Length: 228080
content-disposition: attachment; filename=report 2.xlsx
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
Connection: Close
<binary data>
```

When the first one is seen in Fiddler the browser correctly prompts to save the file. When the second one is seen in Fiddler, nothing observable happens in the browser. Same behaviour in both chrome and firefox.

Any idea why this is happening?

**EDIT**: ASP.NET code that produces the second response

```
Response.Buffer = false;
Response.ContentType = @"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AppendHeader("content-length", genstream.Length.ToString());
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}.xlsx", filename));

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
genstream.Position = 0;

int n;
while ((n = genstream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024) ) > 0)
{
    Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, n);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it wasn't a problem with the response but a problem with the request. Both the HTTP responses in the OP are valid, but the link on the page that produced the second one was inside an asp ajax panel (UpdatePanel). I've been staring at this problem for too long and know too little about HTTP protocol to look into the exact cause of it but the differences in the request headers were these fields:

Working (outside ajax panel):

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
```

Not working (inside ajax panel):

```
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
X-MicrosoftAjax: Delta=true
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: */*
```

Problem is now gone after removing the link from the ajax panel. "Connection: Close" is still in the (now working) header so that was obviously nothing to do with the problem.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually, I think your problem was that the AJAX library was making the request via XMLHttpRequest (ie. not the request/response headers), and trying to make sense of the result  (which it couldn't), and the browser's normal handling of file downloads must not kick in on XMLHttpRequests.

Answer (score 1):

The space in the *filename* parameter value might cause this. Try the [*quoted-string* syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.2.4) instead:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="report\ 2.xlsx"
```

See also [RFC 2183](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2183).

Comment: No change. The first header actually works with spaces in the filename too.

Comment: It was a good guess though. But RFC treats space as TEXT => allowed

Comment: No, the space in the filename is not allowed. You need to use the quoted-string syntax in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here:

```
 Connection: Close
```

A lot of browsers - especially for downloads - use 100-and-continue to read the headers and check the length of the content. The second will not allow the browser to do that.

---

### (UPDATE)

This is generated because of this line:

```
 Response.Buffer = false;
```

Remove it and it should work as a charm!

Comment: I initially thought that until I read RFC2616 "HTTP/1.1 defines the "close" connection option for the sender to signal that the connection will be closed after completion of the response".  So it doesn't close until after file has been transferred

Comment: The client may support using a 100 then making another request for the actual thing, but if the server just responds with a 200, it should work.

Comment: I'm guessing this header field must be what is causing it as it is the only major difference between the two headers. Unfortunately I have no idea why the server is putting that field in or how to stop it. :/

Comment: @sqwerty can you put the code/snippet where you are outputting the second one?

Comment: Added it to the question. I've also tried a few other variations using different response writing methods to no avail. The code there is also basically identical to the code that produces the first header.

Comment: No dice! If I remove that line (and add a Response.Flush() afterwards) the "Connection: Close" field stays in there and the result is the same. ;(

Comment: @sqwerty are you sure buffer is not off at the page level as well? Make sure buffer is on. Apart from this, I have no clue although I will look into keep-alive in the requests. Post an update with that if there is a difference.

Comment: Finally got to the bottom of it. I've posted an answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually a little surprised the first one is working - I thought browsers were pretty picky about case in HTTP headers.

Try changing the "content-disposition" header to "Content-Disposition".

Comment: “Field names are case-insensitive.” (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2)

Comment: No difference. I'm guessing the fact the first one is working means the header names can't be an issue.

Comment: I stand corrected.  (Thanks for the reference Gumbo.)  Must have been something else I was dealing with that was case-sensitive.